# Centering the center of a image in a div

Tags: html

I've to display some html images in my application whose width can vary greatly but the important part of the image is always on center with a width of approximately 120 px.

Trying to display the image with all its width (or even with a percentage of it) produces some other things of the application not to display properly and if set to a certain width the image can become extremely deformed.

So best thing to do would be to create a div of fixed width and no scrollbar which would only show the center of the image, so if the image is for example 400 px it should show from the width pixel 140 to width pixel 260 if 600 from 240 to 360 and so on (borders wouldn't show).

I see no way with my knowledge to do something like this, hope you can guide me, thanks.

Comment: Please make an effort and show what you come up with.

Comment: The best way to learn is to write code (and maybe fail). Show us how far you have gotten with actual code.

Answer (score 1):

If you know image size you can do like this

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px; /* Outer box width */
    height: 200px;  /* Outer box height */
    overflow: hidden;
}
.image img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px; /* 50% of image width */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a div with your image as background and give it this CSS property:

```
background: url(path to your image) no-repeat center center;
```

If you want the image to have an optimal size to fit in the container you can use:

```
background-size: cover;
```